# android capture image from camera and display in another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-image-capture, android-capture

I want to capture image on button click and display the same image in another activity. The below code is capturing image but displaying in the same activity. How can I take image to next activity? What changes to be added?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int pic_id = 123;

Button camera_open_id;
ImageView click_image_id;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    camera_open_id = findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
    click_image_id = findViewById(R.id.click_image);

    camera_open_id.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        // Create the camera_intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE it will open the camera for capture the image
        Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Start the activity with camera_intent, and request pic id
        startActivityForResult(camera_intent, pic_id);

    });

    verifyStoragePermissions(MainActivity.this);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == pic_id) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        click_image_id.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}

private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I recommend sticking with one activity and using two fragments (or two composables) to represent the two screens.

Comment: @ CommonsWare - Can u please share a proper example?

Comment: I do not know what you consider "a proper example" to be. Fragments have been around for a decade, and there is quite a bit of educational material on the topic. Most up-to-date books and courses on Android app development will cover fragments, and some will cover Jetpack Compose and composables. For example, I cover fragments in [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/).